# Formatting table in latex

Tags: latex

I would like to ask how to format table above in latex - table is pretty decent but I would like to have "model" bit right not at the very end, also I would like to have no space at the very right of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{table in stack}
\author{petr102030 Hrobar}
\date{November 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \label{exp_rmse} 

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Model & \multicolumn{1}{c}{RMSE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{MAE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{MAPE} & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Holt-Winters (add.) & 1256.361 & 924.962 & 3.518 &\\ 
Holt-Winters (mul.) & 1238.799 & 909.395 & 3.457 &\\ 
Parab. Trend (model 4) & 2228.310 & 1792.471 & 7.959 &\\ 
Lin.Trend (model 5) & 3074.307 & 2545.426 & 11.339 &\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at [booktabs](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/), a LaTeX package for "Publication quality tables".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The "Model" is at the leftmost boarder of your table because the default padding is shallowed by `@{\extracolsep{5pt}}`. If you remove this, you'll get the padding back. (However the usual advice is to remove this padding, so please consider carefully if you really want to do this)
- only specify as many columns as you have in your table and not 8 like in your example
- with the `siunitx` package you can align the numbers nicely by their decimal markers
- as already mentioned by Picaud Vincent the booktabs package is very useful to create nice looking tables. Amongst other things, it improves the vertical spacing around rules
- using `\label{}` only makes sense if there also is a caption it can reference
- I suggest to remove all the unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}{...}`, they don't do anything useful and can mess up the formatting

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{table in stack}
\author{petr102030 Hrobar}
\date{November 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering  
\begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=4.3]S[table-format=4.3]S[table-format=2.3]} 
\toprule
Model & {RMSE} & {MAE} & {MAPE} \\ 
\midrule 
Holt-Winters (add.) & 1256.361 & 924.962 & 3.518 \\ 
Holt-Winters (mul.) & 1238.799 & 909.395 & 3.457 \\ 
Parab. Trend (model 4) & 2228.310 & 1792.471 & 7.959 \\ 
Lin.Trend (model 5) & 3074.307 & 2545.426 & 11.339 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

[image]